# python cant use a function to change the value of a variable

Tags: python, function

I'm rather new to python and was wondering why the function and therefore the if statement returns "100" instead of "83" in the code below. I'm not sure if I'm missing something obvious but it seems as if it should work.[This is the code I'm refering to:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFmsn.png)

```
playerhp = 100
def attack1(x):
    x = (x - 17)
    return x

while playerhp > 0:
    enemyattack = input("please type the word 'attack': ")
    if enemyattack.upper() == "ATTACK":
        attack1(playerhp)
        print(playerhp)
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Code is text; please copy and paste that text here. A screenshot is not suitable.

Comment: Your function isn't going to modify that global object, nor would you want it to if you understood the ramifications. Try reading a Python tutorial so you understand about scoping.

Comment: @MrN3MESIS No. Do not post your code in a comment. Do you actually expect people to try to read that? Post it in the original question. The easiest way is just to copy and paste from your text-editor, then highlight what you pasted and press control-k

Comment: I'll do that now, thanks for the advice :) Also, Martijn Peters, I've only just signed up for the forum, may I ask why a screenshot is unsuitable?

Comment: I added the code in an edit, if someone goes and peer reviews it it'll show up for all of you.

Comment: Thanks for the help Cody

Comment: @MrN3MESIS for the future, try to keep your questions self-contained on this site, not everyone wants to follow links.  Also, if we need to run your example, we can't copy-paste code from an image into our IDE, and its a pain to retype it.  You'll get less help that way.  You can paste your code into your questions, highlight it all, and hit Ctrl + K (or hit the code button above the edit area) to format it.

Comment: There are two approaches for that. Added in the answer. Hope that will help.

Comment: @Cody Alright then, I'll make sure to do that next time, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment above, this issue comes down to scoping.  Try googling that for more info, but I'll try to give a beginner level explanation here.

When you declare a variable, it exists in a specific scope, and can only be accessed by variables in the same or a lower scope.  For example,

```
var1 = 5
if var1 < 6:
   print(var1)
   var2 = 7
print(var2) #error on this line
```

`var1` exists in the highest scope in this example, so it is accessible to lower ones, so the `print(var1)` line works fine.  However, `var2` is in a higher scope than the statement attempting to print it, and as such it cannot find the variable.  Since Python forces nice formatting, you can think of scope broadly as each level of indentation.  If you have to go to a section more indented, it can find it, but if you need to go through a section that is less indented to find it, then you can't.

This extends to functions.  Your function `attack1` exists in a different scope than what is inside your while loop, and the variable `x` only exists within that function.  As such, when you modify `x`, it only modifies it in that scope, not the original.  It is beyond the scope of your original question, but look up what `passing by value` and `passing by reference` mean, and how they apply to Python.  As other answers point out, you can fix this by assigning the `return value` of x to the original number you are passing in, i.e.

```
playerhp = attack1(playerhp)
```

to take the new number, 17 less than it used to be, and reassign it to the original value, so it assumes this new value instead.

**Edit with regards to what other answers suggest**

Some people suggest modifying the global variable directly.  (I'm assuming Python 3 here, I don't know which version you're using or if Python 2 is even different), you can do that.  Python is a little funny about scoping out of functions, but it is simple to rewrite your attack function like this:

```
def attack1():
   global playerhp
   playerhp -= 17 #shortcut to subtract 17, same as playerhp = playerhp - 17
```

and you can call it simply with

```
attack1()
```

and it will work the same way.  Many programmers would shy away from using global variables if you can avoid it, but that is very subjective and they'll fight all day about that until the end of time.

Comment: Am I correct in saying then that by not assigning "attack1(playerhp)" to the variable "playerhp" I'm just effectively changing the value of playerhp inside the function as a parameter and nowhere else, meaning that the print statement is ignoring that and simply printing out playerhp as it is first assigned?

Comment: It is related to scope. When you call `attack1(x)`, a copy of `playerhp` is passed to the function which gets updated. But the actual value of `playerhp` remains the same. Hence, in order to update the value, you have to either update `playerhp` once value is returned by function OR, use same reference to variable within function which is achieved by `global`

Comment: @MrN3MESIS ditto what Moinuddin just said.  As I said in my answer, google "passing by value" and "passing by reference", and figure out which one Python uses.  That is a critical piece of information to understand in every single programming language.  Hint: your `x` not modifying the value of `playerhp` suggests passing by value.

Comment: Awesome, looks like I've got some reading to do, thanks for the help Moinuddin and Cody.

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign the return value of `attack1` to `playerhp`:

```
def attack1(x):
    x = (x - 17)
    return x

playerhp = 100
while playerhp > 0:
    enemyattack = input("please type the word 'attack': ")
    if enemyattack.upper() == "ATTACK":
        playerhp = attack1(playerhp)
        print(playerhp)
    else:
        break
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks. May I ask why you have changed where the variable is assigned,  is it just good practice?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example of your code:

```
playerhp = 100


def attack1(x):
    x = (x - 17)
    return x

while playerhp > 0:
    enemyattack = input("please type the word 'attack': ")
    if enemyattack.upper() == "ATTACK":
        playerhp = attack1(playerhp)
        print(playerhp)
    else:
        break
```

But the most important about your question is your really understand how passing arguments works, there are tons of sites explaining that, here's just [one](http://www.python-course.eu/passing_arguments.php)

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to achieve it.

*Approach 1*: 
Update `playerhp`'s value based on value return by `attack1()`. For example:

```
>>> playerhp = 100
>>> def attack1(x):
...     return x -= 17
... 
>>> playerhp = attack1(playerhp)
>>> playerhp
83
```

*Approach 2*: Do not pass `x` as param to `attack1()`. Instead use `global playerhp` within function like:

```
>>> playerhp = 100
>>> def attack1():
...     global playerhp
...     playerhp -= 17
... 
>>> attack1()
>>> playerhp
83
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#this works for me. You were not printing the result of the function. 
def attack1(x):
    return(x-17)

playerhp=100
while playerhp>0:
    enemyattack= input("Please type the word 'attack':")
    if enemyattack.upper()=="ATTACK":
        x=attack1(playerhp)
        print (x)

    else:
        break
```